# MVC + EF4 + POCO - How to go about storing the Entity Context?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, poco

I'm making a start on an MVC project, having gone through the MvcMusicStore tutorial. I'm trying to get my head around how the POCO-generated data/entity context is intended to be stored.

In the samples, the controller generates a copy of the entity context, and all operations complete there:

```
        MusicStoreEntities storeDB = new MusicStoreEntities();

        //
        // GET: /Store/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // Retrieve list of Genres from database
            var genres = from genre in storeDB.Genres
                         select genre.Name;
            [...]
```

If I'm to split my solution into layers, what is the standard practice (or key options) for retaining the context? Do I generate it in the controller, and pass it to the repository, or is it possible for the repository to keep a general-use copy?

I understand that the the above would be necessary to use the Unit of Work pattern.

My layers are:

- Data (edmx file)
- Entities (Generated from POCO)
- Repository
- Mvc web app

My other questions:
- What is the overhead of generating the context?
- As there is no .Close(), and it doesn't implement IDisposable, is the ObjectContext behind it generating individual connections, connection pooling, sharing a single instance?
- Is it possible to lock an ObjectContext if it's passed around between layers / operations too much?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ObjectContext` does implement `IDisposable`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't want to go into too much detail/code here, so i'll just mention some points:

1. Your controller can work with **multiple** repositories
2. There should be **one repository** per *aggregate root*
3. Controller work amongst multiple repositories are made possible by *Unit of Work*
4. Use a DI container to handle lifetime management of Unit of Work (which is actually the context)
5. Do not use singletons for the Context, let the DI container instantiate/dispose of the context **per HTTP request**

Comment: BTW - i can show some sample code on specific areas if you wish, but there is a LOT of code to accomplish the above.

Comment: No problems. It's definitely the most important.

Comment: I think the gist here is that do not try keep the context alive across requests. There is not much overhead in instantiating it as it is designed to do all its work in a deferred manner. I.E.: Only when you are working with the entities.

Comment: @Slappy - spot on. I also disable Lazy Loading so that queries/context is only used when i say so.

Answer (score 2):

I create a single repository for each controller and put my context in there. The rules I follow are that the repository handles anything that I might want to mock (not really the definition of repository, but it works for me). The repository can call other repositories if necessary, but the controller shouldn't have to know about it. The Context is an instance property of the repository and is created on demand (I haven't taken the leap into IOC yet). If the repository calls another repository, it passes the Context instance.

It looks a little like this...

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IMyControllerRepository Repository { get; set; }
    public ActionResult MyAction(int id)
    {
        var model = Repository.GetMyModel(id);
        return View(model);
    }
}

public class MyControllerRepository : IMyControllerRepository
{
    public MyContext Context { get; set; };
    public MyModel GetMyModel(int id)
    {
        return (from m in Context.MyModels
                where m.ID = id
                select m).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers. Is the repository instantiated per page (when the controller is loaded), or a single repository assigned to any MyController created?

Comment: "The repository can call other repositories if necessary..."  Surely this is one case where you would use a service layer?

Comment: @Overflew - I instantiate the Repository in the controller as needed. Controllers are instantiated when requested so this would be per request. Since the Repository contains a reference to the context, you would not want to share it between requests.

Comment: @awrigley - Not sure what you mean by "service layer". If you mean something like WCF or web services, then definitely not. You want to be able to share the context between the repositories so that they can all work from the same data and you don't have to deal with attaching/detaching objects from context. To be fair, I try to see myself as more of a pragmatist than a purist and don't believe in creating something complex when something simple works great.

Comment: No, service layer as a go between between the repositories and the controllers

Comment: Aww, I see what you mean. You could do that, but I find it simpler just to have a single layer. My controllers tend to focus on a single entity so the repository tends to work with just a single entity. For me and the way I tend to structure my code, having a service layer would feel too much like extra code for no real gain. The few interactions that I have with other repositories are typically handled pretty easily within the repository and I don't feel that it is unmaintainable (actually quite the opposite, it's very easy to maintain).